# Trying to get a css card flip to line up in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flip, card

I am trying to get my card that I created using HTML and CSS to be able to line up with bootstrap.  It currently is only in the middle of the section and I can not figure out how to get 4 of these cards to line up in one row and then another 4 to line with in a row under it.

Here is the HTML

```
    <div class="card-container mx-auto mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card card-front">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="Assets/aspentree.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the
                        card's content.</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the
                        card's content.</p>
                    <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-back">
                <div class="card-body bg-warning">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please supply your css as well.

Comment: It is a card flip so it has a front and back side, back side contains the button that will link to the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the card you made is working as expected and now you just want to show four of them in a row using bootstrap then you can realize this simply by wrapping the cards html in bootstrap-grid columns classes like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="card-container mx-auto mt-5">
                <div class="card card-front">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Assets/aspentree.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-back">
                    <div class="card-body bg-warning">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="card-container mx-auto mt-5">
                <div class="card card-front">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Assets/aspentree.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-back">
                    <div class="card-body bg-warning">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="card-container mx-auto mt-5">
                <div class="card card-front">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Assets/aspentree.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-back">
                    <div class="card-body bg-warning">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="card-container mx-auto mt-5">
                <div class="card card-front">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Assets/aspentree.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the
                            card's content.</p>
                        <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-back">
                    <div class="card-body bg-warning">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ./col -->
    </div> <!-- ./row -->
</div><!-- ./container-fluid -->
```

I have divided the `row` in four `cols` so to make a new row you can replicate it.

Also try to set width of `.card-container` in percent instead of rem to make it more contained in the column.

Hope this is what you asked and it solves the problem.

Comment: The card works well its just right in the middle of the page.  When I add the code above it becomes 4 very skinny and long cards that go past two of the next sections

Comment: .card-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 18rem;
  perspective: 200rem;
  height: 666.98px;
}

.card-container:hover .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-container:hover .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.9s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-back .card-body {
  position: relative;
}

.card-body a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15% 0 0 -23%;
}

Comment: CSS is above ^^^^^^

Comment: OK, I got what the issue is, please check the answer, I have edited it.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks so much.  Now I can adjust everything and add those links to websites on the hrefs and images.

Comment: Happy to help, and if you find the answer suitable and solved your problem, can you mark it accepted, Thanks